# How to generate swagger without writing spec files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, swagger, swagger-ui, rswag

I am looking for a gem which will generate swagger doc and showed it on the swagger UI, I came across `rswag` gem but it requires spec file needs to be present for generating the swagger doc

Is there any gem that will auto generate swagger doc if I put it in on the API controller?

Comment: Check out https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations/#ruby

Comment: @Helen above mentioned library is outdated, so kindly provide one with the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

I built an open-source tool to make this easy. Instead of integrating at the code level, the project uses a local proxy to analyze real development traffic and updates your API spec when it observes new behavior in the API. https://github.com/opticdev/optic

For Rails, the only change you have to make is to make the switch from using:

```
rails server
```

To starting your API with Optic's start command.

```
api start
```

When new API behavior is detected, you can add it to your spec using our UI. [Here's an example](https://design.useoptic.com/example-sessions/todo-example/diff/fakeSessionId/urls).